# How does the Stripe payment gateway work for the WP Shopping Cart?

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I'm looking at the Stripe Payment Gateway for the WordPress Shopping Cart plugin (http://tribulant.com/docs/wordpress-shopping-cart-plugin/6050#doc2) and I'm wondering if anyone has used this.

The problem I'm anticipating is that Stripe has no support for accepting multiple items. So what will appear on the user's Stripe report?

A single total with nothing itemized?

What happens if the customer wants to return just one item.

Thanks for any insight here.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Stripe for subscriptions but if you want to work it like a shopping cart I would do:

1. Check if the Stripe customer exists [by retrieving a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#retrieve_customer)
2. If the customer exists then [add all the items as a new invoice item](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_invoiceitem)
3. If the customer does not exist, create the customer then add the invoice item

Just remember that you don't have to have a plan or a subscription for your customer.

Everything that you need to know can be found in the [Stripe PHP documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#).

Good luck and happy coding

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I gave you the points but I was really looking for feedback from someone who had actually worked with the Tribulant plugin, But from what you say, and what Stripe says, there's no way to make Stripe a real shopping cart. They'll only take the total amount, so if you want to refund one item you have to do a partial refund of that amount, and there won't be anything on the Stripe report that identifies the item. If you want to send the customer and merchant invoices that show individual items you need to send these emails from within the shopping cart software.